# URL hack not working to populate the Account Id

Tags: force.com

I have a Opportunity List button that is of the URL content source. This button is on the Opportunity related list on the Contract page layout. The URL is:

```
/006/e?retURL=%2F{!Contract.Id}&RecordType=012250000004Vbx&ctrcid={!Contract.Id}&accId={!Contract.AccountId}
```

When I click this button, the Opportunity edit comes up where the Record Type is correct and where the Contract lookup field is also correctly populated. However, the Account lookup field is left blank and furthermore, whenever I edit this URL further to prepopulate fields such as StageName or Amount, these fields too are left blank.

(For example: &StageName=x)

I have done so many different tests to try and figure out what is going on but to no avail.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I have resolved this.

Having selected the button that navigated me to the edit page, I went to 'view page source' and searched for the field ids that I wanted.

For example, I have now amended my URL with the following:

```
/006/e?retURL=%2F{!Contract.Id}&RecordType=012250000004Vbx&ctrcid={!Contract.Id}&opp3=TEST&opp4_lkid={!Contract.AccountId}
```

because opp3 is the field Id for Opportunity Name and opp4_lkid is the field Id for Account Name, according to view page source. For example:

```
Account Name</label></td><td class="dataCol col02"><div class="requiredInput"><div class="requiredBlock"></div><input type="hidden" name="opp4_lkid" id="opp4_lkid" value="000000000000000" />
```